# `xiaoqiang` in `xiaoqiang (192.168.31.1) `

Tags: networking

I try to trace the route:

```
$ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (64.13.192.76), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  xiaoqiang (192.168.31.1)  5.694 ms  2.697 ms  4.784 ms
 2  117.101.192.1 (117.101.192.1)  3.123 ms  6.509 ms  3.693 ms
```

What's `xiaoqiang`? It means cockroach literally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because it starts with 192.168.*, I guess it might be your router. Probably you purchased a router from China, and the info I found in Chinese websites shows that your router is a “XIAOMI” (the company that makes MI MIX 2) router. 
This should be configurable.

Comment: Good research! This link supports your theory: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/xiaomi/mini

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute` looks up host names [normally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21612/117549), so I would check your /etc/hosts file; otherwise, your DNS servers (`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf`) are returning that name for that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a xiaomi Mi Wi-Fi 3 pro (R3P) router and after doing a network analyse with the Fing app, I saw that this connection was mentioned as Xia0Qiang. So yes this is a Chinese router.